# Authenticate automatically from one domain to another domain

Tags: authentication, jwt, basic-authentication

I have an web-application running on Node which have an view with some HTML links which are on different domain and server. This other domain (running on Apache) is protected with basic authentication and with an technical/application username and password which the Node-process uses example when making REST calls to this another domain.

Main web-application doesn't have any authentication because access is restricted with whitelist IPs. Earlier link to another domain did contain embedded credentials but they was removed (because they was not anomore supported with newer Chrome versions).

What choices I have to successfully login/authenticate automatically to this another domain? With automatically I mean that other domain shouldn't ask any credentials if the user comes from the main web-application via HTTP link.

I think I could use HTTP referer for this, but I have feeling that is not the most secure and/or best approach. Could the Node process e.g. use JSON web tokens (JWS) to authenticate to another domain and somehow bypass or send the some authentication automatically to another domain and allow access for user browser without asking the credentials from the user.

Sorry if this is stupid question but I couldn't find simple solution to this from help of the search.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the referrer does not bring any safety into the request. And your feelings about JWT is also right, it can be used with a Node process and delivers a great solution for the another domain. The JWT authentication is always a two phase process and for the first basic auth is frequently used. As you already have that on another domain (if I understood well), you are done with the first phase. I made a solution like that recently and it works well. JWT authentication is one of the easiest to implement, I encourage you to go that way.